# change all text elements in a tag in list

Tags: jquery, text, replace, element

A part of my page contains an unsorted list inside a div element:

```
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>This text works</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a><This text is the Problem></a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code I get from the Server automatically. The Problem is when the text inside the a tag contains < or > the result is not correctly displayed as these symbols are interpreted as html elements. So I have to go through the list and put every text element in Quotation marks so that an element like this:

```
<a><Text></a>
```

will become:

```
<a>"<Text>"</a>
```

Can someone tell me how t achieve this? I found ways to replace elements but they want an id.

Comment: You didn't control the server part ?

Comment: that should really be taken care of server side

Comment: are those always a tags?

Comment: `$('#list a').each(function() { $(this).html( '"' + $(this).html() + '"' ); });`

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdzjotcv/). Long, hard way, but should work.

Comment: By all means try to get the server side part resolved. Your HTML is not valid HTML, so you can get different behaviours and problems in different browsers. The < and > inside texts should be rendered as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Any other solution is a hack that sonner or later will bite you

Comment: The Software of my Company is installed at many customers servers. When we Change something at the Server we would have to deploy two different web-templates depending on what Server Version the costumer is using. So changing it from Server side is sadly not an Option, altough I totally agree with you.